# Wired sql query

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
sqlite> select sid,max(amount) from(select * from Am where year=2014);
1,600
sqlite> select sid from (select sid,max(amount) from(select * from Am where year=2014));
3
```

Where 3 come from?! the only option is 1..
Whats going on?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why the difference. Both should be equivalent to `SELECT sid, MAX(amount) FROM am WHERE year=2014` No reason to make it all complicated.

Comment: I want only the column sid. you are correct I can short it. but still why the result is different from the possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select sid, max(amount)` doesn't seem very well-defined. I think you're assuming it will give you the sid for the row that has the max amount, I don't think that is a valid assumption.

I would write this as

```
select sid from Am where year = 2014 
and amount = (select max(amount) from Am where year = 2014)
```

which can return multiple rows if there's a tie for the maximum amount.

Comment: Of course, this could return multiple rows that have the same amount... I'd go with `select top 1 sid from Am where year = 2014 order by amount desc`.

Comment: @Luann, yes, it can return multiple rows. but i'm not sure the OP wants just one.

Answer (score 1):

Now you know what indeterminate means,if you don`t aggregate you need to group by, other databases dont even allow this operation.
Suppose you have these values:

```
sid amount
1   600
1   500
3   400
3   200

select sid,max(amount) from t
```

Will return an indeterminate value from sid and 600 for MAX.Sid might be correct or might not,that`s what indeterminate means,because you don`t have any control on that column.A proper query would be

```
select sid,max(amount) from t where year = 2014 GROUP BY sid
```

Or

```
select max(amount) from t
```